# JSON parser keeps failing on newline even after adding another backslash

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, parsing

So I'm making a messaging platform for a school project, and I'm trying to both protect my database, protect XSS attacks, and also allow every single character, including newlines.

So far, I've got everything covered, except newlines. JSON parser cannot for the live of it parse a simple newline.

I've tried prefixing the newline with another backslash (\\n) but that STILL doesn't work!

[image: Error Msg]

What should I do?!

**Edit 1:** Added code that generates the JSON data

```cs
string message = "[";
string uid;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++) {
    if (StringCipher.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5)) > int.Parse(data.Rows[i][5].ToString())) {
        queryDelete = "DELETE * FROM Bubbleland WHERE MessageID = " + data.Rows[i][0] + ";";
        commandDelete = new OleDbCommand(queryDelete, connection);
        commandDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } else {
        message += "{\"mid\":" + data.Rows[i][0];
        if (data.Rows[i][1].ToString() == "")
            uid = "user";
        else
            uid = data.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        message += ", \"uid\":\"" + uid;
        message += "\", \"name\": \"" + data.Rows[i][2];
        message += "\", \"color\": \"" + data.Rows[i][3];
        message += "\", \"content\": \"" + data.Rows[i][4];
        message += "\"}";
        if (i + 1 < data.Rows.Count) {
            message += ",";
        }
    }
}

message += "]";
```

**Edit 2:** Added JS processing code

```js
async function fetchMessages() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ASPX/bubblelandFetch.aspx",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var container = document.getElementById("messages-container");
        var uid;
        container.innerHTML = "";

        console.log(data);

        for (var i in data) {
            var message = '<div id="' + data[i]["mid"];
            message += '" class="message ' + data[i]["color"] + '">';
            message += '<div class="profile-container">';

            if (data[i]["uid"] == "user")
                uid = "/Media/user"
            else
                uid = "/Media/Profile/" + data[i]["uid"];

            message += '<img src="' + uid + '.png"/>';
            message += '<span>' + data[i]["name"] + '</span></div>';
            message += '<div class="content">' + data[i]["content"] + '</div>';

            container.innerHTML += message;
        }
    },

    complete: function () {
        setTimeout(fetchMessages, intevral);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Where does this _JSON_ come from? The best way to create valid, parseable JSON is to create it automatically from another data structure

Comment: Straight from my database, preprocessed and packaged into a neat `Response.Write`

Comment: Like I said, never roll your own JSON. What language / framework is that server-side code? Surely there's a native data-structure to JSON converter available

Comment: This is ASPX/C# with the .NET framework.
I believe that even if there was a native way to convert it to JSON, it wouldn't matter as I need it converted in a custom way from the database.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, an unescaped `\r` was messing up the JSON parser.

Whenever you `Shift + Enter`, it puts `\r\n` instead of a simple `\n`. I had no idea it does this. So in my ASPX backend code, I replace `\r\n` with `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with parsing the string you provided me, I have stumbled across a fix and did further research to understand why this happened in the first place.

To put it simply:
**‘Single quotes “escape” single quotes’**
**“Double quotes ‘escape’ double quotes“**

These quotes mean, when using single quotes to create a string literal, you must escape any single quotes with a backslash `\` for the string literal to be valid. The same goes for when using double quotes to create a string literal, but escaping double quotes with a backslash.

I didn't recognize this issue at first, even though I knew the problem in the first place and I do this *all* the time.

I came across this [Medium article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/the-real-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-javascript-3d00bf720bcd) helps put things together, and I suggest you read it to freshen up on using single/double quotes with string literals.